Get AppSettings from Azure AppConfiguration before web application build
My minimal web api use Azure App Configuration to store several configuration settings.
Now I need to get some values from that configurations before .Build() the web application and I can't find a way to obtain my settings other than use BuildServiceProvider.

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    const string JSON = "json";
    var appSettingsKey = CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.APPSETTINGS.ToLower();
    
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"{appSettingsKey}.{JSON}", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"{appSettingsKey}.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.{JSON}", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    
    builder.Services.Configure<Settings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.EQUINOX_SETTINGS_PREFIX));
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => options.Connect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING))
                            .Select(CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.EQUINOX_SETTINGS_KEY_FILTER, CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.EQUINOX_SETTINGS_LABEL_FILTER)
                            .ConfigureRefresh(refresh => refresh.Register($"{CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.EQUINOX_SETTINGS_PREFIX}:{CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.SENTINEL_KEY}", refreshAll: true))
                            .UseFeatureFlags());

    var buildServiceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var settings = (buildServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Settings>>() ?? null) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostBuilderContext, services, configuration) =>
    {
        configuration.ConfigureLogging(CONSTANTS.CLUSTER.EQUINOX.ToUpper());
        configuration.AddApplicationInsightsLogging(services, hostBuilderContext.Configuration, settings.Value);
    });
    
    builder.UseOrleans(settings);
    builder.AddServices(settings);
    
    var app = builder.Build();

Now I know that calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results
in an additional copy of singleton services, but since I need to register some services that need those settings, for example ApplicationInsights for Serilog, I don't know how to do it.
What is the right way to do it?

You already access builder.Configuration before the build() call. Why would that be any different?

You can use ConfigurationBinder.Get extension method, no need to build service provider. Something along these lines:
// after setting up all configuration sources
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection(CONSTANTS.APP.SETTINGS.EQUINOX_SETTINGS_PREFIX);
var settings = section.Get<Settings>();

// use settings

P.S.
AFAIK the AddJsonFile and AddEnvironmentVariables are added by default for web apps so you should be able to skip it.

One way around this, assuming you host your application in Azure App Service, is to use an AppConfig-backed app setting in your App Service.  This basically gets the web app to expose a value from Azure AppConfig as an environment variable - that way it's available at startup and you will have access to it directly using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myappservicekey").  You've already got a call to builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables() so you should also have access to it using the regular configuration patterns you normally use for everything else too.
Assuming you have an AppConfig with a url of "https://myappconfig.azconfig.io" and a particular configuration key of "myappconfigkey", possibly with a label of "mylabel", then you need to do two things:

In the AppConfig, you need to assign the App Configuration Data Reader role to the managed identity of your web app.  This will let your web app config read those settings - you probably have this set up already since you need your app to read from there anyway.
In the App Service webapp, add an environment variable app setting.  Give it whatever name you like (e.g. "myappservicekey") and make the value @Microsoft.AppConfiguration(Endpoint=https://myappconfig.azconfig.io; Key=myappconfigkey).  If you were using a label as well, make the value @Microsoft.AppConfiguration(Endpoint=https://myappconfig.azconfig.io; Key=myappconfigkey; Label=mylabel).

If using labels and using deployment slots you may want to make the setting a deployment slot setting so you can have different labels per slot.
Save your changes and you should see something like this:
screenshot of configured AppConfig-backed Azure App Service environment variable.  Assuming you have the green tick next to "App Configuration" you're good to go.  If you don't have a green tick, either your permissions or your reference aren't correct.
You won't see the actual value of the AppConfig setting in Azure Portal, just a reference to the appropriate AppConfig key.  This works in very much the same way as KeyVault-backed AppService environment variables, just using @Microsoft.AppConfiguration instead of @Microsoft.KeyVault.  Your application will get the actual value at runtime.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configuration-references for more information.
